# Should [jamming] be linked to [improvisation]?

Tags: discussion, tags

As I contemplated answering [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/133683/78419), I was thinking about the fact that "jamming" is a type of improvisation. I then remembered that we *have* a tag for [improvisation](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/improvisation), with 307 uses. We also have [jamming](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jamming) with only 19. While the word is sometimes used for any kind of informal, recreational music-making, even non-improvisatory, it usually is understood as improvisation, and most of those 19 questions reflect that. Seems to me it's just a difference in cultural words, and maybe there's value in keeping both tags. I don't know a lot about managing tags, but can they be "linked," so that we keep both terms but find all 326 questions?

(Or is my premise faulty from a musicological standpoint—even if all jamming is improv, maybe not all improv is jamming?)

Comment: I think we'd still want a word to mean "informal music-making", and "jamming" is the most common term I know of — maybe the only word I know of, now that I'm thinking about it. Maybe the approach is to retag the "jamming" questions as "improvisation" and then see what's left, if anything.

Comment: @Aaron True, I do see at least 6 just from a cursory overview that are focused on setup or procedure for informal sessions rather than improvisatory aspects. (Including one of dubious validity about sound system setup...) Though I also see that the current tag description is "A group of musicians improvising together with little or no predefined arrangement or structure." Hm, maybe the best thing is simply to *add* [tag:improvisation] to those that include that aspect...

Comment: When I invite a musician to audition for the band, I invite them to a "jam," but the intent is to get them to arrive relaxed to see if they fit into the band rather than to assess their ability to kick out solos. It's more of a social term than "improvisation" implies. Frequently, beer is involved.

Comment: Perhaps this site doesn't deal with the social dynamics of music-making at all, in which case "jamming" could be folded into "improvisation."

Comment: @empty Looking at the questions in [tag:jamming], they're not really something like "how do I find folks to jam with," which a lot of very on-topic "how-to" questions, like "my saxophone is too loud to jam with a harmonica," which has nothing to do with whether they're improvising or playing covers.

Comment: Good question! Jamming has more to do with rock while improv. is used more by jazzers.   Jamming can have no structure at all, whereas improv. is usually over a prescribed set if chords, in my view. So, while there is common ground, the two could easily be kept as separate entities.

Comment: @Tim Meanwhile the classical player stands at an awkward distance and calls *both* improvisation (and wishes he were better at it, and publishes exercise books to try to teach it).

Comment: @Tim Also, when I think of jamming in a Phish-type context I still think of chord changes (often a short, e.g. 4-bar loop)?

Comment: What's a Phish-type context?

Comment: @Tim Yknow, a "jam band." The sort of context that is able to make 20 minutes out of four chords.

Comment: @Tim (Which is, no doubt, unfair to Phish, and a generalization. No disrespect intended. The classical music world used to know how to improvise (Chopin preluding) and/or create "divisions over a ground" (i.e. jam over four-bar loops) and let the skill atrophy.)

Comment: I know now. In France, they wouldn't go as far as *four* chords...

Comment: @Tim "Jamming" is a jazz term and long pre-dates rock. It was in use at least by the 1920s to describe musicians getting together after their paid gigs to "jam" together. Jam sessions are still a staple of the jazz scene.

Answer (score 3):

I think I'm ready to offer a self-answer. One thing that should be clear from the comments and other answer is that both these words can have different uses and understood meanings among different cohorts. For some, the "improvisation" meaning can be primary ("I can learn covers by ear, but I need to get better at knowing what to play while jamming"), for others the "informality" meaning is primary ("I need an instrument I can carry in my pocket so I can jam with anyone spontaneously"). That being the case, we certainly shouldn't merge them or anything of the sort; seems like maybe we should just add [improvisation](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/improvisation) to any [jamming](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jamming) questions that have an improvisatory focus.

Answer (score -1):

Revised answer:

Jamming is not a type of improvisation, to 'jam' means to play with others (like sticking bread together with jam). Jamming implies that the musicians are coming together in the process, building their relationship (musically speaking) with one another. Jamming will probably include improvisation but jamming is not improvisation.

Also note that because of slang usage of the (slang) term, jamming can also refer to a musician on thier own eg. "he has been jamming in his room all day". This would refer to the musician jamming (building the relationship) with his music or instrument rather than other musicians.

Comment: This eaves me just as mystified as before!

Comment: @Tim sorry, I mean the definition of jamming has evolved through slang usage, it can be used to describe playing on your own like 'he's been jammin in his room all day' but that still doesn't explicitly mean he's improvising. Jamming initially meant musicians playing together (like bread with jam).

Comment: Got a source for this? It's one thing to use a term informally with others, it's another thing to say it should be the understood usage especially when talking about how we use tags. A practice session and a jam session feel _very_ different and I'd say both investing in building their relationship and in some ways practice sessions do it more. By that definition I'd also say musicians going out for a slice and talking about musical topics would also fit the definition you gave as it will musically build their relationship outside of playing together.

Comment: sounds good to me! my source? Its in every use of the term, I haven't found an example yet that doesn't fit my definition. Have you heard of companies having jam sessions around a table talking about marketing or some non music related thing?

Comment: https://medium.com/the-masterpiece/jamming-your-way-to-success-understanding-strategy-jams-534b986ae576

Comment: https://www.agilealliance.org/resources/experience-reports/liven-agile-learning-code-jams/

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=agile+jamming&ia=web

Comment: I see your point however I think that if the question specifically talks about improvisation it should be tagged as such. for what question would jamming alone be sufficient illudes me at the moment but i'll try come up with an example

Comment: maybe where improvisation indicates the act alone, jamming includes a component of improv amongst others such as the drummer playing a set beat while the guitarist improvises over it?

Comment: You linked me 3 different sources none of which talk about the musical definition.  If I say scale, the musical context is different. Wikipedia while not being a perfect source shows that jam sessions improv is a definition feature https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jam_session#:~:text=To%20%22jam%22%20is%20to%20improvise,covers%20of%20existing%20popular%20songs.

Comment: I've also been in things called coding jams which very much rely on improv. Even of the business side focuses on togerness, I'd wager the unstructured nature of these is more similar to improv than not

Comment: yeah pretty much. the thing that bothers me still is that jamming covers more than just improvising. maybe it's a mute point but i'll never see it that way unfortunately :(.